# Using Html.BeginForm and ajax call same action conflict?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When I try to add `Ajax` to pass another data into my action controller my model parameter was affected the value was null and my `Ajax` parameter has a value. 
I do not think it is because I am using `Html.beginform('index', 'payable')` and I used `Ajax` `url: '@Url.Action("index", "payable")',` with the same `ActionResult.`

You can see the reference below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "payable", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Amount, new { @class = "form-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ImagePath, new { @class = "form-label" })
            <input type="file" name="file" id="files" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="saveSelected()"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> &nbsp;Submit Payment</button>
        </div>
    </div>{
```

**My Ajax**

```
function saveSelected() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("index", "payable")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { ids: ids },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
     }
```

**My Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index(PayableFormModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file, int[] ids) 
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Html.Beginform and ajax cannot use at same time,even you add a
  onclick function. So the ajax won't work and all data are submitted
  by form. If you want to submit model and any other data, put all them into form or only use ajax.
- When you upload file, model cannot get file's name or path directly. You should store file into a folder or directory,then assign this path to model's imagepath.(Examle code is blew)
- In index page, {} should follow using(), otherwise it will report error.

  ```
   public ActionResult Index(PayableFormModel model,HttpPostedFileBase file,int[] ids)
   {
       string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/image/");
       Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
       file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(filepath, file.FileName));
       model.ImagePath = filepath + file.FileName ;

       return View();
   }
  ```

Comment: Bruce Zhang thank you for reminding that Html.Beginform and ajax cannot use at same time. i try serialize my form to get all data inside. however my ids is null becoz this parameter is outside the form. do you have suggest on how to pass other data outside form ?

Comment: You can refer to this answer:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/11343604/14162739